# Getting "ReferenceError" error while performing multiple chaining of promise in nodejs application for neo4j import using cypher query

Tags: javascript, node.js, neo4j, cypher

I am writing nodejs application using neo4j js driver (and async utility module) to use a project's source js files' data to be imported in neo4j database.

There are 2 folders namely "State"and "City" and a single **"country.js"** file in my test project folder "testapp".
The **"country.js"** file contains the name and id of the countries and the countryid is used as a parameter in the js files present in the folders "State"and "City".

-- snippet from country.js file

```
const countries= [
{ id: "1", label: "USA" }, 
{ id: "2", label: "Scotland" }
];
module.exports = countries;
```

The "State" folder has js files which has naming convention like this: (**Country-1-statelist.js**, **Country-2-statelist.js** and so on).

--Sample from js file present in "State" folder.

```
    const data = {"params":{"country_id":"1"},"items":
    [{"id":"1","label":"Alaska"},{"id":"2","label":"Alabama"}]
      module.exports = data;
```

Similarly, "City" folder has js files which has naming convention like this: (**Country-1-state-1-list.js**, **Country-1-state-2-list.js** and so on).

-- sample from a particular js file present in "City" folder

```
const data = 
  {"params":
   {"country_id":"1","state_id":"1"},

   "items":[
       {"id":"1","label":"New York"},
       {"id":"2","label":"Chicago"}
   ]
        }
 module.exports = data;
```

So,I am trying to add nodes with label Countries, States and Cities such that they would be imported without their relationship being unaltered. But I am getting error in nodejs while trying to use multiple chain promise to import it into my test db.

so, far I was able to import the data present in country.js and other js files from "State" folder. But while trying to do the same from js files of "City" folder, I am getting "ReferenceError: item is not defined" error.

I have created index.js file in nodejs to do so, which has the following code:

```js
const neo4j = require('neo4j-driver').v1;
const driver = neo4j.driver("bolt://localhost", neo4j.auth.basic("neo4j", "testapp"));
const session = driver.session();
const async = require('async');
const appPathway = '/Users/reactor/Documents/testapp';
const country = require(appPathway+'/country');


async.eachSeries(country, (item, callback) => {
 
  const resPromise = session.run(
    `CREATE (c:country {label: "${item.label}", id: "${item.id}"}) RETURN c.id`
  );
  resPromise
  .then((data) => {
    return insertState(item.id);
              }
  )
  .then
   (
    (done) => {
    callback(null);
              }
    )
  .catch
  (
    (err) => {
    callback(err);
             }
  );
},

 (err) => {
  console.log(err);
  session.close();
  driver.close();
          }
  );


function insertState(countryID) {

  let state = require(appPathway+'/State/Country-'+countryID+'-statelist.js');


  return new Promise((resolve, reject) =>{
    async.eachSeries(state.items, (item1,item2, callback) => {
      
      const resPromise = session.run(
        `
        CREATE (s:state {label: "${item.label}", id: "${item.id}"})
        WITH s
        MATCH (c:Country)
        WHERE c.id = '${countryID}'
        CREATE (s)-[r:LOCATED_IN]->(c)
        RETURN c,s
        `
      );
      resPromise
      .then((state) => {
        console.log(state);
        callback(null);
      })
      resPromise
      .then((data) => {
        return insertCity(item1.id,item2.id);
      })
      .then((done) => {
        callback(null);
                  }
        )
    
      .catch((err) => {
        callback(err);
      });
    }, (err) => {
      if(err) {
        reject(err);
      }
      resolve(true);
    });
 }
);
}

// Problem rose when i inserted the following block of  code !!

function insertCity(countryID,stateID)  {
  let city = require(appPathway+'/city/Country-'+countryID+'-state-'+stateID+'-list.js');

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) =>
                  {
    async.eachSeries(city.items, () => {

      const resPromise = session.run(
        `
        CREATE (w:city {label: "${item.label}", id: "${item.id}"})
        WITH w
        MATCH (s:state)
        WHERE s.id = '${stateID}'

        /* How am I suppose to use the countryid parameter here in this cypher query ? As it doesn't have direct relation with label "country" in this query */
             
        CREATE (w)-[r:PRESENT_IN]->(s)
        RETURN w
        `
      );
      resPromise
      .then((city) => {
        console.log(city);
        callback(null);
      })
      .then((done) => {
        callback(null);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        callback(err);
      });
      }, (err) => {
      if(err) {
        reject(err);
      }
      resolve(true);
      });
               }
      );
}
```

I am new to ES6,cypher and promise function which may have caused this problem. Although,
I have looked into most of the posts, blogs and videos related to multiple promise chaining, but still I am unable to figure out how to do it when multiple parameters are present in a single js file and how to use these parameters to pull the data using cypher query.

Any help or suggestion would be really helpful for me now ! Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `insertState()` and `insertCity()`, you are trying to dereference `item.label` and `item.id`, but there is no `item` in scope.